# i want append html content into DIV tag

Tags: testing

```
 var test ="<html><head><title>JSON Template</title><script type='text/javascript'>widgetbuilder.render({'displayParams':{'wtitle':'Columns','target':'wid1','classlist':{"+result+"},'displimit':'5'},'contentParams':{'channel':'news','category':'columns','wid':'widget1','entity':'Article','limit':'6'}});</script></head><body><div><ul id='wid1'></ul></div></body></html>";
 $("#lightbox-panel").append(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

The  tag is nothing more than a container for other tags. Much like the body tag, Div elements are block elements and work behind the scenes grouping other tags together. Use only the following attributes with your div element, anything else should be reserved for CSS

id
width
height
title
style